# send mail from google sheet with given range content in simple html format to single email id--- kindly help me

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-workspace, google-apps-script

[image].

I have developed the sheet with some condition the email should be lite then only it will deliver to me in short period based on the technical details will take desition on my trade. I have verified and many scripts and tried but not suitable for me

Answer (score -1):

Got the query working fine.

```
function sendMail(){
  var recipients = "jaianjaneya@outlook.in";
 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Techinical"); 
 var data = sh.getRange("A1:F14").getValues();
  //var htmltable =[];

var TABLEFORMAT = 'cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" dir="ltr" border="1" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;font-size:10pt;font-family:arial,sans,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #ccc;font-weight:normal;color:black;background-color:white;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;'
var htmltable = '';

for (row = 0; row';

for (col = 0 ;col' + 'None' + '';} 
  else
    if (row === 0)  {
      htmltable += '' + data[row][col] + '';
    }

  else {htmltable += '' + data[row][col] + '';}
}

     htmltable += '';
}

     htmltable += '';
     Logger.log(data);
     Logger.log(htmltable);
MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, 'Crude Oil Buy','' ,{htmlBody: htmltable})
}
```